# Property 'number' does not exist on type 'Record<"id", string>' in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-hook-form

i am using **react hook form** to build demo application.I am using `usefieldarray` to append rows.

https://react-hook-form.com/api/usefieldarray/

but i am getting typescript error

**[image: Property 'number' does not exist on type 'Record<"id", string>' in react js]**

I already defined interface

```
export interface InitiateHoldModel {
  checked: boolean | null;
  containers: Array<ContainerOnHold> | null;
}
export interface ContainerOnHold {
  checked: boolean;
  number: string;
  size: string;
}
```

Here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-kowalevski-c0qjmh?file=/src/ReleaseFields.tsx:0-805

```
import { HookCheckBox, useHookFormContext } from "mui-react-hook-form-plus";
import { useFieldArray } from "react-hook-form";

export default function ReleaseFields(): JSX.Element {
  const { registerState, control } = useHookFormContext();
  const prependKey = "containers";
  const { fields } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: prependKey
  });
  return (
    <>
      <HookCheckBox {...registerState("checked")} />
      <label>B344332</label>
      {fields.length > 0 && (
        <ul>
          {fields.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={index}>
              <HookCheckBox
                {...registerState(`${prependKey}[${index}].checked`)}
              />
              {item.number}
              {item.size}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Use `getValues` to display

```
export default function ReleaseFields(): JSX.Element {
  const { registerState, control, getValues } = useHookFormContext();
  const prependKey = "containers";
  const { fields } = useFieldArray({
    control,
    name: prependKey
  });
  return (
    <>
      {fields.length > 0 && (
        <ul>
          {fields.map((item, index) => (
            <li key={item.id}> // use item.id as key - it's important
              <HookCheckBox
                control={control}
                {...registerState(`${prependKey}[${index}].checked`)}
              />
              <span>{getValues(`${prependKey}[${index}].number`)}</span>
              <span>{getValues(`${prependKey}[${index}].size`)}</span>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Also cleaned up your [App.tsx](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-montalcini-v7z048?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: let me check and update you

Comment: link not updated ...:(

Comment: it's wasn't saved apparently, but it doesn't matter, just use getValues, read more in the docs

Comment: The `getValues` method does not subscribe your component to field value updates; it's a simple getter function. This could lead to stale values being displayed, as `getValues` is only called on component re-render _(it doesn't cause it)_.

Comment: After spending a few hours looking for a solution, looks like the developer abandoned this problem. And this is indeed the solution to this issue, even though it's hacky. The problem with useFieldArray is that is nests an ambiguous data object that's pulled from control and it uses dot notation, so TS can see a real definition.

Answer (score -1):

In React, the context **type** doesn't propagate down the components tree. When calling `useHookFormContext` in your child `ReleaseFields` component, there isn't a way for the hook to know the type of your form values you defined in your parent component unless you explicitly pass the `control` object down for `useHookFormContext` to derive the type from.

The solution would be to import your `InitiateHoldModel` form type down in your child `ReleaseFields` component and pass it into the `useHookFormContext` hook as the first generic type.

```
// App.tsx
export interface InitiateHoldModel { ... }

const defaultValues: InitiateHoldModel = { ... }

function App() {
  useHookForm({ defaultValues })

  return <form>...</form>
}
// ReleaseFields.tsx
import type { InitiateHoldModel } from "./App"

function ReleaseFields() {
  const { registerState, control } = useHookFormContext<InitiateHoldModel>() // pass the form model type here
}
```